# SQL/SSRS how to count customer by each product category when they buy in different shop location

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have encounter a problem when I'm trying to count customer by each product category

Please see below sample dataset:

[image]

I would like the customer to be count like following:

[image]

For the product "Chocolate", even A company & B company bought in different shop location they should only count as 1 customer.
Therefore, customer count should only be 9 but with the following code I wrote it comes out 11.

I wrote a query as follow, have to keep all the information becoz i need them to be work in SSRS to do some analysis

```
Select period
 ,Product
 ,salesshop
 ,customerName
 ,SUM(Qty) AS prodQty
 ,COUNT(DISTINCT customerName) AS CUSTOMERCOUNT
 FROM SHOP_DATA
 group by period
 ,Product
 ,salesshop
 ,customerName
 HAVING salesshop IS NOT NULL
```

Can anyone help me to fix if possible? Thank you!

problem solved with sub-query lol, thanks everyone

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Thank you for reminding! Im new here and well noted! Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain the logic in more detail, why do you only count 9 chocolat ?

Comment: Hello GuidoG, 9 is customer count, not product count, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain in detail the logic you need, but maybe this can help you

first I create a table with the data

```
declare @t table (product varchar(50), salesshop varchar(50), customername varchar(50))

insert into @t (product, salesshop, customername)
values ('cookies', 'SHOP A', 'A company'), ('cookies', 'SHOP A', 'B company'), ('cookies', 'SHOP A', 'C company'), ('cookies', 'NA_SHOP', 'A company'),
       ('candy', 'SHOP A', 'F company'), ('candy', 'SHOP A', 'G company'),
       ('chocoloat', 'SHOP A', 'H company'), ('chocoloat', 'SHOP A', 'I company'), ('chocoloat', 'SHOP A', 'J company'),
       ('chocoloat', 'SHOP A', 'K company'), ('chocoloat', 'SHOP A', 'L company'), ('chocoloat', 'SHOP A', 'M company'),
       ('chocoloat', 'SHOP A', 'B company'), ('chocoloat', 'NA_SHOP', 'B company'), ('chocoloat', 'NA_SHOP', 'A company'),
       ('chocoloat', 'NA_SHOP', 'F company'), ('chocoloat', 'N SHOP', 'A company')
```

Now I can run this query on that

```
select  t2.product, count(t2.customername) as customercount
from   ( 
         select t.product, t.customername
         from  @t t
         group by t.product, t.customername
       ) t2  
group by t2.product
```

the result will be

```
product customercount
candy       2
chocoloat   9
cookies     3
```

Since I don't know the exact logic you need, you need to check the result with your data to see if this is really what you need.

This solution will count the times that a customername appears per product, regardless of the salesshop. So if `A company` appears 3 times for one product, it counts as only one.  This is not only for A company and B company, but for all companies.

I am not sure is this is what you want, so check it with your data.

If this is not what you want, then please edit your question and explain in more detail the logic you need

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the output you show in your image, you only need to group by `product` and nothing else

```
select product, count(distinct customername) as customercount
from shopdata
group by product
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I didnt make the question clear. Actually sample i put here is already after query run. I need all the info to be keep so I can use them as dataset to be work on SSRS. Just the customer count I dont know how to fixed! thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. But I'm quite sure, the result of the accepted answer is exactly the same as the result from my answer or @Maxime Challon's answer and you don't need a subquery for that ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product, COUNT(DISTINCT customername)
FROM shopdata
GROUP BY product
```

will be enough to have your output

Comment: Thank you for replying quick. I didnt make the question clear earlier. Actually I have a largest data set and the sample i put here is already after query run. I need all the info to be keep so I can use them as dataset to be work on SSRS. Just the customer count I dont know how to fixed! thank you.